# How to detect slow GPU on mobile device with three.js?

Tags: javascript, performance, three.js, webgl, gpu

I've define that my games is extremely slow with enabled shadows on old mobile devices (Samsung galaxy S4, IPhone 5). When I turn off shadows it's improving performance greatly.


Does any one know how to detect slow GPU to turn off shadows completely on slow devices or how to improve shadow performance?

I've try to use diferrent `shadow.mapSize` on lights and `shadowMap.type` on renderer and it dosen't improve performance.

Some details:

I use `PerspectiveCamera` and `WebGLRenderer` with render size 1700x667.

Used lights: `new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.7)` and `new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff, 0.4, 4000, 100)`
Used materials: `MeshPhongMaterial`

Answer (score 3):

Options

1. As Andrey pointed out do a benchmark
2. Try using [`failIfMajorPerformanceCaveat: true`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/#5.2.1) when creating the WebGL context.
3. [Make a fingerprint](https://browserleaks.com/webgl). Query all the various `gl.getParameter` stats related to GPU limits and create a fingerprint. See if there are certain fingerprints that = slow.
4. Try getting and using the [WEBGL_debug_renderer_info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WEBGL_debug_renderer_info) extension unmasked renderer/vendor strings (this is really just more data for #3).
5. Like most PC games, have an options screen that let's users choose which graphics features to use.