# Three.js - Limit Resources

Tags: three.js

My pc crashed the other day because I was not aware of how much power WebGL needs.

Is it possible to limit the resources to prevent this from happening?

Thank you very much

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect slow GPU on mobile device with three.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47452428/how-to-detect-slow-gpu-on-mobile-device-with-three-js)

Comment: partially, maybe somebody comes up with another trick for big devices. 
But thanks for the quick reply

Answer (score 0):

The use of the GPU is disabled for hidden tabs, though how this is implemented may vary between browsers and platforms. I know this won't help you determine if a page uses webGL, but its useful to know if you want to conserve resources.

The Lynx browser isn't webGL enabled, though it's text only, which might be a dealbreaker.

Most browsers allow disabling of javascript, no js means no webGL.

Chrome and Firefox allow specific disabling of webGL

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't think that what I'm trying to do is even possible, as I would need to access the resources of the system to monitor and limit them. The only thing I have is the fps panel, but I don't know if it makes much sense to force webgl to stop if the fps drop.